# Restricting a form in a projective variety

Tags: projective-geometry

If I have a symmetrical bilinear form and a projective variety. How do I restrict that form to my variety?

Let's say I'm studying a hyper-quadric.

I get its singular, and I want to classify it.

It occurred to me, as I obtained two planes, to cut with another plane that did not contain any point of the singular, because if there was a cut they had to be real (it was in $P_3(\mathbb{R})$) and if not, they are complex.

But I don't remember how to restrict one vector variety to another.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have edited my question. Thanks